# Android: Auto Rotate not working after setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, autorotate, screen-rotation

I have a video player in which I have two features:

1. If the auto-rotate is disabled and when the user clicks on fullscreen button I force the `orientation` to go in `landscape` view using `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)` and back to portrait view when fullscreen is exited.
2. I have overridden the `onConfigurationChanged` to detect the change in orientation when the auto-rotate feature is enabled by user and change the activity view according to the orientation.

Now the problem with this setup is that if user start the activity and goes in fullscreen and `setRequestedOrientation` get invoked once, later when `auto-rotate` is enabled, the activity doesn't receive the orientation changes and the `onConfigurationChanged` doesn't get called.

I read here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109206/5167868) that they wont work simultaneously.

I would like to know if there a way of implementing both as I have seen players like `MX Player` do this in their app.

Comment: that might be because you force portrait orientation after exitting fullscreen. Try setting not portrait, but automatical orientation: `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`

Comment: But I want it to be in Portrait Orientation if the auto-rotate is disabled.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear earlier and I edited the question. I meant after the user enables auto-rotation, the onConfigurationChanged is not called.

Comment: check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848222/toggling-fullscreen-orientation-like-youtube?answertab=active#tab-top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848222/toggling-fullscreen-orientation-like-youtube?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @SuhasShelar did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

After you fix the orientation of the screen by using `setRequestedOrientation()`, Auto Rotate feature won't work. So to make it work, you may do something like this:

After you set your orientation using: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)`

**Call this:**
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)`

This shall make the auto rotate to work again!

Comment: Doesn't work, my screen changes to landscape and then back to portrait immediately.